# How can i add chart image in excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, chartjs

I have created a chart using chartjs and another table of data using javascript. i want to download this table and chart in excel. table in table format and chart as an image or chart we use in excel. Is there any possible way?

Comment: You could just save your data as a CSV, but that won't solve your chart issue. I seem to recall Excel will happily open HTML that's got a table in (might be wrong) - could be if the chart is rendered as an HTML image it'll pick that up, but I very much doubt you'll find a way to get a real Excel chart in your spreadsheet automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to implement the appropriate parts of [ECMA-376](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/). However, it is outside the scope of this network to provide a full detailed example of the code you'd need to write, which would likely include several hundred lines of code. What I would do, if I were you, is to build the spreadsheet in Excel the way you want to see it, save it, rename the file extension from 'xlsx' to 'zip', and then look through that file as a compressed folder. You'll see all the necessary metadata there. From the JavaScript side, you'll want something like `zipjs` to create the file contents, and then use the standard download technique (create an `a` tag with the `download` property, then `click()` to initiate the download).